# how can I take a dynamic variable in value of JSON?

Tags: regex, perl

I need use the find and replace through regular expression like following

```
use strict;
no strict 'refs';
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Encode qw( encode decode encode_utf8 decode_utf8);

my $data =  
{
    "find_replace" => [
        {   "find" => "(.+?)&",
            "replace"=> "$1"
        }
    ]
};

my $find_replace_arr = $data->{'find_replace'};
my $string  = "http://www.website.com/test.html&code=236523";

my $find = $find_replace_arr->[0]->{find};
my $replace = $find_replace_arr->[0]->{replace};

$string =~ s/$find/$replace/isge;

print $string;
exit();
```

in this code, I only want to "http://www.website.com/test.html" from the string.

I am not able to get replace (key)'s value dynamically, which is $1.

You can Run the above code.

> This code throw the Error Use of uninitialized value $1 in string

Comment: Since your replace variable contains Perl code, try to add an `e` modifier to your regex: `my $string =~ s/$find/$replace/isge`

Comment: Hi Hakon thanks for answer, I checked your code and modify the above code. but still not working. It's given the error Use of uninitialized value $1 in string

Comment: Yes you are right. You need to double the `e` modifier in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to consider. First, the regex `([^&]+)` may not give the desired result, as it is really going to capture and replace with the same capture.. resulting in the same output string (confusing I bet).

Next, the replace string `"$1"`has to be quoted again and `e` modifier has to be doubled.

So try this:

```
my $data =  
{
    "find_replace" => [
        {   "find" => "^(.+?)&.*",
            "replace"=> '"$1"'
        }
    ]
};

my $find_replace_arr = $data->{'find_replace'};
my $string  = "http://www.website.com/test.html&code=236523";

my $find = $find_replace_arr->[0]->{find};
my $replace = $find_replace_arr->[0]->{replace};

$string =~ s/$find/$replace/isgee;

print $string;
exit();
```

Notice the new regex, `^(.+?)&.*` will match the entire string, but the capture `(...)` will be the result to replace.